# Creating inline date_select dropdowns using simple_form and zurb foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, simple-form

I'm using Simple_Form with Zurb Foundation in my rails application.

One of more views has a form with the following date_select

The form fields are showing up stacked rather than inline.  I've checked everything and can't figure out how to get these to show-up correctly.

What am I missing?
You can see the repo at https://github.com/stanrails/momtomom  in the event.html.erb view.

The code for the section is below:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-5 columns">
            <%= f.date_select :eventDate %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I took what you had in the event.html.erb and just made it pure html with foundation and I did not have any display issues. Could you possibly throw up a screenshot showing what issue you are seeing.  A jsbin with the rendered HTML markup would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 4):

One of the workaround is to have something manually like this:

```
form.custom .dropdown.date{
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: this is a great solution!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another take on this I wanted to share which ends up looking like this:

[image]

A little html!

```
  div[class="row"]
    div[class="large-12 columns select-date-wrapper"]
      = f.date_select(:birthdate,
          options = { start_year: DateTime.now.year - 18, end_year: DateTime.now.year - 75, order: [:month, :day, :year], include_blank: true},
          html_options = { class: 'select-date'})
```

A little sass!

```
select.select-date {
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.select-date-wrapper{
  select:first-of-type{
    width: 45%;
  }
  select:nth-of-type(2){
    width: 20%;
  }
  select:last-of-type{
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by checking the html and changing the css of the relevant tags:

`<%= f.date_select :date %>` produces:

```
<div class="field col-md-6">
    <select id="invoice_date_1i" name="invoice[date(1i)]">
    <select id="invoice_date_2i" name="invoice[date(2i)]">
    <select id="invoice_date_3i" name="invoice[date(3i)]">
</div>
```

With "Invoice" being the model name here. Therefore, in your css you can add

```
#yourModel_date_1i, #yourmodel_date_2i, #yourmodel_date_3i { width: 30%; }
```

for an easy fix.