# How can I configure simple_form to inline datetime elements? Foundation Zurb

Tags: zurb-foundation

My question is pretty straightforward. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to inline simple_form datetime input fields. Its really aggravating me. I've tried a couple of methods but nothing seems to work. For starters, I've read the documenation for simpleform and nothing. From the docs, I've tried this:

```
<legend>Start Time</legend>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-3 columns"><%= f.input :start, label: false, as: :date, date: :inline %></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-3 columns"><%= f.input :start, label: false, as: :time, time: :inline  %></div>
  </div>
```

Nothing.

I've implemented this code as a workaround using CSS taken from this answer. [CSS workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178816/creating-inline-date-select-dropdowns-using-simple-form-and-zurb-foundation?lq=1)

This is NOT what I want to do because the form is hideous on different browsers.

Lastly, I think that my answer is in the initializer files for simple form shown here:

```
config.wrappers :default, class: :input,
hint_class: :field_with_hint, error_class: :field_with_errors do |b|
## Extensions enabled by default
# Any of these extensions can be disabled for a
# given input by passing: `f.input EXTENSION_NAME => false`.
# You can make any of these extensions optional by
# renaming `b.use` to `b.optional`.

# Determines whether to use HTML5 (:email, :url, ...)
# and required attributes
b.use :html5

# Calculates placeholders automatically from I18n
# You can also pass a string as f.input placeholder: "Placeholder"
b.use :placeholder

## Optional extensions
# They are disabled unless you pass `f.input EXTENSION_NAME => :lookup`
# to the input. If so, they will retrieve the values from the model
# if any exists. If you want to enable the lookup for any of those
# extensions by default, you can change `b.optional` to `b.use`.

# Calculates maxlength from length validations for string inputs
b.optional :maxlength

# Calculates pattern from format validations for string inputs
b.optional :pattern

# Calculates min and max from length validations for numeric inputs
b.optional :min_max

# Calculates readonly automatically from readonly attributes
b.optional :readonly

## Inputs
b.use :label_input
b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :hint }
b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
end

# The default wrapper to be used by the FormBuilder.
config.default_wrapper = :default

# Define the way to render check boxes / radio buttons with labels.
# Defaults to :nested for bootstrap config.
#   inline: input + label
#   nested: label > input
config.boolean_style = :nested
```

The thing is where do I start. I've found related topics but its all regarding Bootstrap. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.